# How can I select an option based on the value of an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, html-select

I have similar inputs and a `select` in my page. If I enter an input value I want to automatically select the option by its value.

The problem is that it works for one input but I have many of those, one the same page and script change values for all of them. What i need achieve that i can enter value for one of them then for second one, but i can't change classes.

```js
//select option from padalinys 
(function($) {
  $('.test2').on('blur', function(e) {
    let inputVal = $(this).val();

    $('.padalinys option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === inputVal) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
    })
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="text-black">Pad. kodas</label>
    <input type="text" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control test2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Padalinys</label>
    <select class="form-control padalinys" name="padalinys[]">
      <option value="1">test - 1</option>
      <option value="2">test - 2</option>
      <option value="3">test - 3</option>
      <option value="4">test - 4</option>
      <option value="5">test - 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="text-black">Pad. kodas</label>
    <input type="text" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control test2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Padalinys</label>
    <select class="form-control padalinys" name="padalinys[]">
      <option value="1">test - 1</option>
      <option value="2">test - 2</option>
      <option value="3">test - 3</option>
      <option value="4">test - 4</option>
      <option value="5">test - 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="text-black">Pad. kodas</label>
    <input type="text" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control test2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Padalinys</label>
    <select class="form-control padalinys" name="padalinys[]">
      <option value="1">test - 1</option>
      <option value="2">test - 2</option>
      <option value="3">test - 3</option>
      <option value="4">test - 4</option>
      <option value="5">test - 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have two `test2` ids - duplicate ids is invalid HTML.

Comment: i changed it to class. Same class but need different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `class` instead of `id` and then use `$(this).parent().parent().find(".padalinys option")` to traverse through only that select which needed to be changed.

Here is demo code :

```js
//select option from padalinys 
(function($) {
  //use .test2
  $('.test2').on('blur', function(e) {
    let inputVal = $(this).val();
    //input->div->div->find select box
    var $selector = $(this).parent().parent().find(".padalinys option");
    $selector.each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === inputVal) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
    })
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="text-black" for="test2">Pad. kodas</label>
    <input type="text" id="test2" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control test2">
    <!--added class-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Padalinys</label>
    <select class="form-control padalinys" name="padalinys[]">
      <option value="1">test - 1</option>
      <option value="2">test - 2</option>
      <option value="3">test - 3</option>
      <option value="4">test - 4</option>
      <option value="5">test - 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="text-black" for="test2">Pad. kodas</label>
    <input type="text" id="test2" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control test2">
    <!--added class-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Padalinys</label>
    <select class="form-control padalinys" name="padalinys[]">
      <option value="1">test - 1</option>
      <option value="2">test - 2</option>
      <option value="3">test - 3</option>
      <option value="4">test - 4</option>
      <option value="5">test - 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: glad i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: Use `closest(".row")` to get to the closest parent element with the class `row` and `find()` to select the options that are related to the input field.

```js
(function($) {
  $('.test2').on('blur', function(e) {
    let inputVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.padalinys option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === inputVal) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
    })
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="text-black">Pad. kodas</label>
    <input type="text" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control test2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Padalinys</label>
    <select class="form-control padalinys" name="padalinys[]">
      <option value="1">test - 1</option>
      <option value="2">test - 2</option>
      <option value="3">test - 3</option>
      <option value="4">test - 4</option>
      <option value="5">test - 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="text-black">Pad. kodas</label>
    <input type="text" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control test2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Padalinys</label>
    <select class="form-control padalinys" name="padalinys[]">
      <option value="1">test - 1</option>
      <option value="2">test - 2</option>
      <option value="3">test - 3</option>
      <option value="4">test - 4</option>
      <option value="5">test - 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the source i expanded the code a little to more specific values

```js
//select option from agebetween 
(function($) {
  //use .ageinput
  $('.ageinput').on('blur', function(e) {
    let inputVal = $(this).val();
    //input->div->div->find select box

    if (inputVal > 17 && inputVal < 26) {
      var $selector = $(this).parent().parent().find(".agebetween option:nth-child(1)");
      $selector.each(function() {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      })
    } else if (inputVal > 25 && inputVal < 36) {
      var $selector = $(this).parent().parent().find(".agebetween option:nth-child(2)");
      $selector.each(function() {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      })
    } else if (inputVal > 35 && inputVal < 46) {
      var $selector = $(this).parent().parent().find(".agebetween option:nth-child(3)");
      $selector.each(function() {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      })
    } else if (inputVal > 45 && inputVal < 56) {
      var $selector = $(this).parent().parent().find(".agebetween option:nth-child(4)");
      $selector.each(function() {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      })
    } else {

      var $selector = $(this).parent().parent().find(".agebetween option:nth-child(5)");
      $selector.each(function() {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      })

    }


  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label class="text-black" for="test2">Enter age</label>
      <input min="18" max="100" type="number" id="ageinput" name="padkodas[]" class="form-control ageinput">
      <!--added class-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <label class="text-black">Age between</label>
      <select class="form-control agebetween">
        <option>18-25</option>
        <option>26-35</option>
        <option>36-45</option>
        <option>46-55</option>
        <option>56-100</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```